How to dynamically display an image based on the environment in visionOS
I'm trying to display the light/dark variant of the logo based on the environment in visionOS but couldn't.
I used the following approach:
@Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme

HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Spacer()
    Group {
        let logoName = colorScheme == .dark ? "HorizLogoWhite" : "HorizLogo"
        if let _ = UIImage(named: logoName) {
            Image(logoName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(height: 80)
                .opacity(logoOpacity)
                .scaleEffect(logoScale)
        } else {
            Text("\(logoName) not found")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
    Spacer()
}
.padding(.vertical, 20)


There's not really a notion of "dark mode"/"light mode" in visionOS. If you're using the default translucent glass background you'll see that it adapts well to bright rooms and dark rooms.
Note also: if you want to swap image assets based on dark/light mode (or any other varying trait), best practice is to do that in the assets catalog (Assets.xcassets), by adding multiple Appearance values. Much more robust and maintainable than swapping out in your code.
